# How to find a point estimate for a given random sample of exponential distribution given the sample variance and four out of five sample values?

Tags: statistics, variance, exponential-distribution, parameter-estimation

> Let $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\right)$ be the observed values of a random sample of size $5$ from an exponential distribution with parameter $\beta$. Out of five observed values four are given as $x_1=2$, $x_2=4$, $x_3=5$, $x_4=5$ and if the sample variance is $s^2=1.5$, then a point estimate of $\beta$ is?

In this question a valid method of solving would be to assume a value $x$ for $x_5$ and finding sample variance with one equation and one variable. However, this neglects the first statement about the distribution that is being used and fails to take advantage of the properties that come along with the distribution. What is the significance of that first statement and how does it play a role in the solution?

Comment: The information about $s^2$ allows you to solve for $x_5$. The information about $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ being samples from an exponential distribution will be relevant for the task of providing a point estimate of $\beta$.

Comment: You should say whether parameter $\beta$ is mean or rate. // Knowing four of five observations and sample variance $S^2.$ you should be able to find the firth observation. Then use the five observations to estimate $\beta.$

Comment: @BruceET , 1) what do you mean by mean/rate (I assume it to be the $\beta$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\beta x}$). 2) how would you estimate $\beta$ here, assuming you know all 5 values?

Comment: Then $\beta$ is the population mean, and sample mean $\bar X$ is a reasonable point estimator of $\beta.$ So if you had $x_5=4,$ then $\bar X = \hat\beta = 4.$ // Sometimes the parameter of an exponential dist'n is rate $\lambda = 1/\beta,$ so you always have to say what the parameter is.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET, if you were to add that as an answer I would gladly upvote. However, is there a simple way to find the value of $x_5$ other than expanding and solving the quadratic equation? Otherwise I can self-answer the question if that is ok..

Comment: You are permitted answer your own question. Suggest you take what you know now and post an answer.  Going to bed now, but I'll look early tomorrow. // My method of finding $x_5$ was to guess it must be an integer and start in R with code `a = 1; x = c(2,4,5,5,a); var(x)` to get $S^2 =3.3.$ Then let `a=2`, etc. Short search. Not especially proud of that but it worked, and you asked.

Answer (score 1):

We assume the random sample to be $\{2,4,5,5,x\}$

Since, we are given the sample variance which is defined to be:

$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{(x-\bar x)^2}$$

$$\bar x=\frac{16+x}{5}$$

Therefore, we get,

$$6 = \left(\frac{6+x}{5}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{4-x}{5}\right) + 2\left(\frac{9-x}{5}\right)^2 + 16\left(\frac{x - 4}{5}\right)^2$$

which implies,

$$150 = 20x^2 -160x +470$$

which implies, $x = 4$ upon solving the quadratic equation.

Now, a suitable point estimate for the parameter $\beta$ here would be the sample mean $\bar x$. Thus, we have,

$$\beta = \bar x = \frac{20}{5} = 4$$

Comment: Coming soon to a stat course near you: In this situation $\frac{\bar X}{\beta}\sim\mathsf{Gamma}(4,4).$ So you can find $L$ and $U$ that cut probability .025 from lower and upper tails of this dist'n. Easy algebra to isolate $\beta$ gives 95% CI for $\beta$ of form $(\bar X/U \le \beta \le \bar X/L)$ so R code `4/qgamma(c(.975,.025),4,4)` returns 95% CI $(1.825,14.681)$ for $\beta.$